# netbeans crash on ubuntu

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been having multiple crashes of Netbeans 8.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. I've sent multiple java crash reports into Oracle until their jsp was broken and one couldn't submit java crash dumps. 
It crashes in different places and once in awhile it behaves OK, so it is not a 'solid' failure, just a frequent one..

It literally has crashed on startup. This is running Oracle 8_45 also.
The following is up through the current thread

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fcc9f005060, pid=7628, tid=140517782222592
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fcc9f005060
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fcc8c103000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_Java, id=7652, stack(0x00007fccd85e7000,0x00007fccd87e8000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x00007fcc9f005060

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fcc52b9d468, RBX=0x00007fcc52b9d468, RCX=0x00000000f5f3f3d8, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007fccd87e19c8, RBP=0x00007fccd87e1a38, RSI=0x00000000f5f3f3d8, RDI=0x00007fcc52b9d650
R8 =0x00007fccf23a5000, R9 =0x00007fcc800423c0, R10=0x00007fccfb4089c0, R11=0x00007fccde9e23c0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007fccd87e19e0, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00007fcc8c103000
RIP=0x00007fcc9f005060, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000014
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fccd87e19c8)
0x00007fccd87e19c8:   00007fccdd007640 00007fccd87e1a38
0x00007fccd87e19d8:   00007fccdd007640 00000000f5f3f3d8
0x00007fccd87e19e8:   405d400000000000 00000000f5f3f3d8
0x00007fccd87e19f8:   00007fccd87e19f8 00007fccdcf1c14d
0x00007fccd87e1a08:   00007fccd87e1a48 00007fccdcf1cdf8
0x00007fccd87e1a18:   0000000000000000 00007fccdcf1c158
0x00007fccd87e1a28:   00007fccd87e19e0 00007fccd87e1a48
0x00007fccd87e1a38:   00007fccd87e1a90 00007fccdd007640
0x00007fccd87e1a48:   00000000f5f3f3d8 00007fccd87e1a50
0x00007fccd87e1a58:   00007fcc55d1a2e8 00007fccd87e1b60
0x00007fccd87e1a68:   00007fcc55d1b140 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1a78:   00007fcc55d1a698 00007fccd87e1a48
0x00007fccd87e1a88:   00007fccd87e1b48 00007fccd87e1ba8
0x00007fccd87e1a98:   00007fccdd00798d 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1aa8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1ab8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1ac8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1ad8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1ae8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1af8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1b08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1b18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fccd87e1b28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000144
0x00007fccd87e1b38:   0000000000000075 00000000f5f3f3d8
0x00007fccd87e1b48:   00000000f41b4660 00000000fb812c60
0x00007fccd87e1b58:   00000000f5f3ed40 00000000f550bad8
0x00007fccd87e1b68:   00007fccd87e1b68 00007fcc55d19b09
0x00007fccd87e1b78:   00007fccd87e1cb0 00007fcc55d1b140
0x00007fccd87e1b88:   0000000000000000 00007fcc55d19ee0
0x00007fccd87e1b98:   00007fccd87e1b48 00007fccd87e1c60
0x00007fccd87e1ba8:   00007fccd87e1cf8 00007fccdd00798d
0x00007fccd87e1bb8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fcc9f005060)
0x00007fcc9f005040:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX={method} {0x00007fcc52b9d468} 'getWidth' '()D' in 'java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D$Double'
RBX={method} {0x00007fcc52b9d468} 'getWidth' '()D' in 'java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D$Double'
RCX=0x00000000f5f3f3d8 is an oop
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double 
 - klass: 'java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D$Double'
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007fccd87e19c8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fcc8c103000
RBP=0x00007fccd87e1a38 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fcc8c103000
RSI=0x00000000f5f3f3d8 is an oop
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double 
 - klass: 'java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D$Double'
RDI={method} {0x00007fcc52b9d650} 'setRect' '(DDDD)V' in 'java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D$Double'
R8 =0x00007fccf23a5000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007fcc800423c0 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007fccfb4089c0: <offset 0xf9f9c0> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fccfa469000
R11=0x00007fccde9e23c0 is at entry_point+32 in (nmethod*)0x00007fccde9e2250
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007fccd87e19e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fcc8c103000
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007fcc8c103000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007fccd85e7000,0x00007fccd87e8000],  sp=0x00007fccd87e19c8,  free space=2026k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00007fcc9f005060
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.HighlightsViewUtils.paintBackgroundHighlights(Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljavax/swing/text/AttributeSet;Lorg/netbeans/modules/editor/lib2/view/DocumentView;)V+24
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.HighlightsViewUtils.paintHiglighted(Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;Lorg/netbeans/modules/editor/lib2/view/DocumentView;Lorg/netbeans/modules/editor/lib2/view/EditorView;IZLjava/awt/font/TextLayout;III)V+537
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.HighlightsView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)V+36
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.ParagraphViewChildren.paintChildren(Lorg/netbeans/modules/editor/lib2/view/ParagraphView;Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;II)V+104
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.ParagraphViewChildren.paint(Lorg/netbeans/modules/editor/lib2/view/ParagraphView;Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)V+196
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.ParagraphView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)V+12
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.DocumentViewChildren.paint(Lorg/netbeans/modules/editor/lib2/view/DocumentView;Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)V+525
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.DocumentView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;Ljava/awt/Shape;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)V+45
j  org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.view.EditorView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljava/awt/Shape;)V+21
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljava/awt/Shape;)V+48
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+65
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+45
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+3
J 6695 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (44 bytes) @ 0x00007fccddf09aec [0x00007fccddf09a20+0xcc]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd16913c [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x3fc]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
j  javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+205
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
j  javax.swing.JLayer.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+38
j  javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+2
j  org.netbeans.core.multiview.SplitLayerUI.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+3
j  javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+32
J 6695 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (44 bytes) @ 0x00007fccddf09aec [0x00007fccddf09a20+0xcc]
j  javax.swing.JLayer.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+14
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
j  org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol.TabbedContainer.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+53
J 9182 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (669 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd3d49f4 [0x00007fccdd3d3fe0+0xa14]
J 8037 C1 javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V (409 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd1691c4 [0x00007fccdd168d40+0x484]
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIIIII)V+41
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Image;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)V+163
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)Z+116
j  javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)Z+231
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)V+51
j  javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(IIII)V+683
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(IIII)V+138
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(IIII)V+65
j  javax.swing.JLayer.paintImmediately(IIII)V+59
j  javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI.paintImmediately(IIIILjavax/swing/JLayer;)V+7
j  javax.swing.JLayer.paintImmediately(IIII)V+29
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(IIII)V+65
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+81
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x7197dc]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0x27c
J 948  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd35ad95 [0x00007fccdd35acc0+0xd5]
J 10695 C1 java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (32 bytes) @ 0x00007fccddb4ad3c [0x00007fccddb4aa40+0x2fc]
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Ljava/util/Map;)V+154
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions()V+46
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions()V+73
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(Ljavax/swing/RepaintManager;)V+1
j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run()V+37
J 4875 C1 java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V (69 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd5bcb14 [0x00007fccdd5bc900+0x214]
J 4680 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (149 bytes) @ 0x00007fccddaff31c [0x00007fccddafec80+0x69c]
J 4678 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void; (60 bytes) @ 0x00007fccddafe2e4 [0x00007fccddafe240+0xa4]
J 4677 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x00007fccddafdee4 [0x00007fccddafde80+0x64]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x7197dc]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0x27c
J 948  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd35ad95 [0x00007fccdd35acc0+0xd5]
J 2756 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (80 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd82f9e4 [0x00007fccdd82f780+0x264]
J 10371 C1 org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (43 bytes) @ 0x00007fccde829a44 [0x00007fccde829940+0x104]
J 4889 C1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V (295 bytes) @ 0x00007fccdd9609cc [0x00007fccdd95edc0+0x1c0c]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x681f31]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x321
V  [libjvm.so+0x6823d7]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*)+0x47
V  [libjvm.so+0x718280]  thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*)+0xa0
V  [libjvm.so+0xa5c86f]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xdf
V  [libjvm.so+0xa5c99c]  JavaThread::run()+0x11c
V  [libjvm.so+0x910de8]  java_start(Thread*)+0x108
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x8182]  start_thread+0xc2


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fcc8086d000 JavaThread "Annotation Refresh" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7710, stack(0x00007fcc50948000,0x00007fcc50b49000)]
  0x00007fcc8c485000 JavaThread "Inactive RequestProcessor thread [Was:org.netbeans.modules.parsing.spi.Scheduler/org.netbeans.modules.parsing.spi.Scheduler$2]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7709, stack(0x00007fcc4fc6c000,0x00007fcc4fe6d000)]
  0x00007fcc98058000 JavaThread "org.openide.text Editor Initialization" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7708, stack(0x00007fccd967b000,0x00007fccd987c000)]
  0x00007fccec00b800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=7630, stack(0x00007fccf84ba000,0x00007fccf86bb000)]
  0x00007fcc8c663800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7677, stack(0x00007fcc53a92000,0x00007fcc53c93000)]
  0x00007fcc8c30d800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=7671, stack(0x00007fcc53e93000,0x00007fcc54094000)]
  0x00007fcc8c284800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7670, stack(0x00007fcc54094000,0x00007fcc54295000)]
  0x00007fcc8c2c8800 JavaThread "Deadlock Detector" [_thread_blocked, id=7669, stack(0x00007fcc54295000,0x00007fcc54496000)]
  0x00007fcc8c5e4800 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7668, stack(0x00007fcc5489f000,0x00007fcc54aa0000)]
  0x00007fcc7002f000 JavaThread "File Watcher" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7660, stack(0x00007fcc6b9fd000,0x00007fcc6bbfe000)]
  0x00007fcc8c49e000 JavaThread "Editor Parsing Loop (201411181905)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7655, stack(0x00007fccd0550000,0x00007fccd0751000)]
  0x00007fcc8c499000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7654, stack(0x00007fccd0951000,0x00007fccd0b52000)]
  0x00007fcc8c469000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=7653, stack(0x00007fccd0b52000,0x00007fccd0d53000)]
=>0x00007fcc8c103000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_Java, id=7652, stack(0x00007fccd85e7000,0x00007fccd87e8000)]
  0x00007fcc8c101800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=7651, stack(0x00007fccd87e8000,0x00007fccd89e9000)]
  0x00007fcc8c0ff800 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7650, stack(0x00007fccd89e9000,0x00007fccd8bea000)]
  0x00007fcc8c0dc800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7649, stack(0x00007fccd8bea000,0x00007fccd8deb000)]
  0x00007fcc8c02c800 JavaThread "RequestProcessor queue manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7648, stack(0x00007fccd947a000,0x00007fccd967b000)]
  0x00007fccec586000 JavaThread "Spellchecker" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7646, stack(0x00007fccd987c000,0x00007fccd9a7d000)]
  0x00007fccec570000 JavaThread "CLI Requests Server" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7645, stack(0x00007fccda3be000,0x00007fccda5bf000)]
  0x00007fccec549000 JavaThread "Active Reference Queue Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7644, stack(0x00007fccda5bf000,0x00007fccda7c0000)]
  0x00007fccec2ae000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7642, stack(0x00007fccdace9000,0x00007fccdaeea000)]
  0x00007fccec2a0800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7641, stack(0x00007fccdaeea000,0x00007fccdafeb000)]
  0x00007fccec29f000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7640, stack(0x00007fccdafeb000,0x00007fccdb0ec000)]
  0x00007fccec29c000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7639, stack(0x00007fccdb0ec000,0x00007fccdb1ed000)]
  0x00007fccec29a800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7638, stack(0x00007fccdb1ed000,0x00007fccdb3ee000)]
  0x00007fccec265800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7637, stack(0x00007fccdb3ee000,0x00007fccdb5ef000)]
  0x00007fccec263800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7636, stack(0x00007fccdb5ef000,0x00007fccdb7f0000)]
```

I can add more if requested.

Comment: I guess the best is you [open an issue](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html).

Comment: I would if I could. I finally found that site yesterday. I had been trying to use  http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp, which I had used in the past but now it asks for information there is no input field for, OS release and  version. It seems like the kind of mistake one would have caught before they put that servlet into production.